# How to check for infinity values in Matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, zero

I have a program which returns 2 variables, denoted as `X` and `Y`. 
The size of `X` is 3 by 5 and`Y` is 3 by 3. I want to check if the values are infinity or not but Matlab does not do so. In general, this is what I would be doing for any matrix, but this code does not work for the matrix shown in picture.  What is the proper way?

```
clear all


  Y = [

      NaN +    NaNi      NaN +    NaNi      NaN +    NaNi
      NaN +    NaNi      NaN +    NaNi      NaN +    NaNi
      NaN +    NaNi      NaN +    NaNi      NaN +    NaNi];

  if (isnan(Y))
      disp( ' values in Y are infinity')
  end

  X =  1.0e+017 *[

      NaN +    NaNi      NaN +    NaNi      NaN +    NaNi      NaN +    NaNi  -7.8517 - 0.0000i
      NaN +    NaNi      NaN +    NaNi      NaN +    NaNi      NaN +    NaNi  -3.9259 - 0.0000i
      NaN +    NaNi      NaN +    NaNi      NaN +    NaNi      NaN +    NaNi  -1.9629 - 0.0000i];
  if (isnan(X))
      disp( ' values in X are infinity')
  end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From `help if`:

> The statements [in the IF's body] are executed if the real part of the [conditional] expression has all non-zero elements.

In your case,

```
>> isnan(X)
ans =
     1     1     1     1     0
     1     1     1     1     0
     1     1     1     1     0
```

which would evaluate to `false` if used as-is in an `if` condition.

It is usually better to be explicit:

```
if any(isnan(X(:))
    disp('X contains a NaN'); end
```

would display the message if there is a `NaN` *anywhere* in `X`, and

```
if all(isnan(X(:))
    disp('X is all-NaN'); end
```

would display the message only if *all* elements in `X` are `NaN`.

Also take a look at [`isfinite`](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/isfinite.html) - this allows you to detect `inf` and `NaN` in one go.

Answer (score 0):

your code will display `values in X are infinity` if entire matrix is `NaN`. if there is even one none-NaN element in your matrix it will display nothing.
If you want a `disp( ' values in X are infinity')` for every `NaN` in your matrix, you shall go through the matrix and check each element. Do it with two nested loops:

```
for i1=1:row
   for j1=1:col
      if (isnan(X(i1,j1)))
         disp( ' values in X are infinity')
      end
   end
end
```

Comment: I am getting error `Undefined function or variable 'NaNi'.` when I ran your code. Also, is this operation legal where I want to store the matrix `X` in another matrix which is 3 dimensional i.e, X1(:,:,k) = X; where `k = 2` I then want to interchange the values from `X1` such as  `X=X1(:,:,k-1); `  Can you please help how to eliminate the error and how to do this operation

Comment: @SKM, this is because you type just "NaNi". This is the way Matlab show the expression, but you can't write it like that. You should do something like `X=NaN + NaN*i` (while `i` is not a variable in your workspace). If you want to check if there is even one NAN element in X you should use `any`: `if any(isnan(X)) disp('values...'); end`

Comment: your `Y` matrix have 3 rows and 3 colmuns. each element is equal to ` NaN + NaNi` . if it is true you shouldn't  have any error. I've checked my code. consider that `NaNi` itself wont be recognized by matlab. it should be with a `NaN` (i.e. `NaN + NaNi`). check this for your error

Comment: to your second question, yes it is possible. you can assign a 2-D matrix to one of 3rd dimensions of another 3-D matrix. i.e.  ` a = ones(3,3,3); b=rand(3,3); a(:,:,2) = b; `.